# Suggestions for estimating Heat Load (watts) in an evaporator (antifreeze - hot fluid, R744 - cold fluid)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger, refrigeration

I am working on simulating an evaporator for an R744 refrigeration cycle.
Here, I have inlet conditions of R744 with low pressure (around 30 bar) and low temperature(-8°C) and that of antifreeze (35% eth-glycol in water) with higher temperature (around 4°C) and am uncertain about its pressure (assuming 1 bar for now). I want to calculate the heat load and the outlet temperatures.

Here I am using the eta-NTU method to estimate Heat Load, however, at this pressure, CO<sub>2</sub> tends to change to vapour at around -6°C, meaning I have to account for a phase change in my calculations.

The common way of dealing with phase change in the eta-NTU method is to set C<sub>max</sub> = 0. I think this is assuming that the hot fluid changes phase. However, in my case, it is the cold fluid that changes phase, meaning my C<sub>min</sub> values will have significant changes.

This means I am no longer able to use the eta-NTU method as the formula
Q = eta_ntu × Cmin × delta(T) is no longer valid.

How can I estimate the heat load and subsequently outlet conditions in my case?

My approach right now is to estimate the overall heat transfer coefficient (U) and know the area (A).
Q = U × A × delta(T_antifreeze - T_co2) + mass_flowrate × Hfg  where Hfg = vapour enthalpy - fluid Enthalpy at saturation condition of CO<sub>2</sub> at the pressure (29.5 bar).